# Django Async View - Model __str__

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, python-asyncio

I'm trying to convert my existing Django 4.1 app to async due to performance reasons.  It's more of a struggle than I initially anticipated.

Below is some test code:

```
async def diagrams(request):

    tests = await sync_to_async(list)(Test.objects.filter(name='Test 1'))
    print(tests)

    return render(request, 'analyticsApp/test.html')


class Test2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
    testForeignKey = models.ForeignKey(Test2, editable=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        # Need to get foreign key here in async way but this function cannot be async ??
        return self.name + '_' + self.testForeignKey.name
```

So I kind of figured out how to "filter" objects using async_to_async.  However, a problem that I'm struggling to solve is using `__str__` in a Model.  All of my models use `__str__` to give accurate string depcitions of the model. It seems like this cannot be done ?  I tried to convert `def __str__` to `async def __str__` but django is not awaiting this when it is being called so it causes problems.

Any idea how to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the async don't increase your performance.

In your code you work don't correct with async. Str should work with existing data, without ask to database.
Therefore you should receive needed data before instance init.

In your case you can made:

```
obj = Test.objects.select_related("testForeignKey").get(**something)
```

Also you can use defer/only.
The query works async, after that you get your Str(object) normally.

Comment: The above is just test code.  Real code contains various requests and database calls.  A lot of waiting for external calls.  I'm not exactly sure how to above will help but I will try.  The problem is Django does not allow async def str

Comment: Try to optimize the Sync code before you goes to async world. If you not shure in select_related, try to read the documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: The main issue is an async context is calling def str.  Thus, def str needs to be async def str.  Django does not allow that.  I understand the select_related issue but I don' think it will help in this case.  But thanks anyways for your help so far

Comment: I understand - you want do something async. But Str(obj) should works with existed Data in memory und Not binded with io-flow. In this case async change nothing. If in your project this is not so - probably you do something wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks I think the other answer here helped as well.  If I can figure out how to select_related nested foreign keys then the problem is solved

Comment: Got it... users = await sync_to_async(list)(Test.objects.filter(name='Test 1').select_related('testForeignKey__testForeignKey'))

Answer (score 1):

I have't used much the async support but as a work around you can use a `select_related`

```
async def diagrams(request):

    tests = await sync_to_async(list)(
        Test.objects.filter(name='Test 1')
            .select_related('testForeignKey')
    )
    print(tests)

    return render(request, 'analyticsApp/test.html')
```

Comment: Mmm.... this seems to be working for the specific example because Django does not need to fetch foreign key in async thread.  However, for more complex work done in def str it will obviously not be a solution.  I'm still wondering how you can convert def str to async def str somehow

Comment: Any idea how to use this with nested foreign keys ?  Let's say testForeignKey needs to reference another foreign key ?  If I can do this somehow then I think I can solve this issue

Comment: Got it... users = await sync_to_async(list)(Test.objects.filter(name='Test 1').select_related('testForeignKey__testForeignKey'))

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is the  `print(tests)`

That's when the query gets evaluated and at that point `__str__` gets called to print the list of tests. Simply put, if you don't print them `__str__` will never get called in an async context!

Also the .filter just prepares the sql statement and there's no need to wrap it in the sync_to_async unless you really need a list there which will cause it to evaluate. In this example you don't seem to need it as you can pass a queryset directly to your template for rendering and it will be evaluated there. You can simply do this:

```
tests = Test.objects.filter(name='Test 1')
return render(request, 'analyticsApp/test.html', { 'tests':tests })
```

If you absolutely need to print them then you simply wrap the print in a sync_to_async

```
await sync_to_async(print)(tests)
```

Or if you need to print them as a list then

```
test_list = await sync_to_async(list)(tests)
await sync_to_async(print)(test_list)
```

Print needs to be sync to access the . notation of accessing related fields.
Same stands for using the dot notation to access related fields in your template. If you are then wrap the render in a sync_to_async and await it.

```
return await sync_to_async(render)(request, 'analyticsApp/test.html', { 'tests':tests })
```

All you manage with select_related is to cause the evaluation of the related fields to happen at the same time as the creation of the list in sync context and that's why it works with the dot notation in your template or with print.